# Tensorflow object detection API only using CPU and Crashing

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Hi everyone i'm trying to use the object detection API from Tensorflow. i'm currently using

TF 2.2.0 and TF-GPU 2.2.0

RTX2080 cudatoolkit v10.1 CUDNN v7.6.5

i'm trying to train the model ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 on my own Dataset.

when using the `model_main_tf2.py` ,the training worked but somehow it always crash after 400 steps. and even though i add this line `with tf.device(tf.DeviceSpec(device_type="GPU", device_index=0)):` if i open Task manager to see the GPU usage, it always says 5% or less and the CPU around 34%
after it crash i alway get the same Error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Step 500 per-step time 0.531s loss=0.864
I0129 00:07:36.263110 12688 model_lib_v2.py:651] Step 500 per-step time 0.531s loss=0.864
2021-01-29 00:07:58.237349: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:29] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
2021-01-29 00:07:58.258278: F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:273] Unexpected Event status: 1
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

any idea why it could happen?

Answer (score 2):

this is happen when your Ram getting full ,and to solve this ,you need to decrease number of

> batchsize  in
> **pipeline.config**
> and retriain again

or train on google Colab
or upgrade your Ram size.

Regards.